# How to display data of user logged in in an html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a designed a register form, from which data is getting stored in the local storage and I want to display logged in user's data in success.html. I have tried using the following code but its not working. Please help!

Login.html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Login</title>
<body>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" action="success.html" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" />
            <span class="help-block" style="display:none">Username is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="password">Password<span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
            <span style="display:none">Password is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" onclick="validate()">Login</button>

            <a href="register.html" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="display"></div>
    <script src="controller.js">
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller.js--

```
localStorage.setItem("key_users", JSON.stringify(users));

 var rusers = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('key_users' ) );

function validate(){
var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  for(var p in rusers){
      console.log(p+':'+rusers[p].username+'|'+rusers[p].email);
      if(username==rusers[p].username && password==rusers[p].password){
      alert("Logged in successfully");
      function Redirect() {
               window.location="success.html";
               messageBox.innerHTML = "Welcome,  " +rusers[p].firstname+ "  here are your details: " + "</br>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "Name: " + rusers[p].firstname + "<br/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "UserName: " + rusers[p].username + "<br/>";
  messageBox.innerHTML += "EmailId: " + rusers[p].email + "<br/>";
            }
      }

  }
```

success.html--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Welcome User</h2>
<div id="display"></div>
<script src="controller.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: user details is not getting displayed in success.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of code to debug for others. I would recommend starting again with very small working example and then work your way up to the functionality you need. All of this while keeping the application functioning and taking notice of errors and use debugging tools (console.log, google development toolbar etc) when needed.

If something breaks you immediately know what broke it and it will be much easier to help you with problems or questions.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is not for transfer data between pages. It only works on the page that it created. Test below cod in two page `a.html`, `b.html`:

```
//a.html:
    if (!sessionStorage.getItem("data"))
        sessionStorage.setItem("data", "data you saved");
    else
        alert(sessionStorage.getItem("data"));
```

After first refresh you can see the alert with **data you saved**

and in b.html:

```
alert(sessionStorage.getItem("data"));  //alert null
```

It means data is not transfered to b.html.